# Spring TestRestTemplate POST and PUT not working when adding Netty as a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty

When adding

```
    compile 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.6.Final'
```

as a dependency to my Spring Boot project all my unit tests using `TestRestTemplate.postForObject(...)` and `TestRestTemplate.put(...)` start to fail. It seems the request body isn't transmitted because I get the following error

```
Failed to read HTTP message:... HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing
```

The service is still working and accepts POST and PUT requests. I checked that using curl. `TestRestTemplate.getForObject(...)` on the other hand is still working. Using a normal `RestTemplate` for POST and PUT is also working.

I tried to configure the TestRestTemplate (*right solution, wrong implementation -> see my answer*)

<s>@TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
            RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            restTemplateBuilder.detectRequestFactory(false)
            restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory())
            return restTemplateBuilder
        }
    }</s>

with no effect. I also tried to use `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` which didn't work either. I tried to configure the `HttpMessageConverter` using the `GsonHttpMessageConverter` for example... no effect.

Answer (score 0):

`TestRestTemplate` isn't working because Spring Boot configures it to use `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` when it finds Netty on the classpath and the `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` doesn't seem to work.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7240
and https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14860

To make `TestRestTemplate.postForObject(...)` and `TestRestTemplate.put(...)` I had to provide a `RestTemplateBuilder` `@Bean` and configure it to use `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. The `RestTemplateBuilder` `@Bean` in the question has a few errors. It's supposed to look like this

```
@TestConfiguration
static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().detectRequestFactory(false).requestFactory(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.class);
    }
}
```